# Is it correct to say "you have to wind the watch all the way to the end"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-request, phrase-choice

My friend has just bought a mechanical watch, he needs to wind it many rounds until he hears a click or can't wind any more.

**Is it correct to say?**

- "**you have to wind the watch all the way to the end**"
- "**you have to wind the watch all the way clicked**"
- "**you have to wind the watch all the way until you hear a click**"
- "**you have to wind the watch all the way until you feel resistance**”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. you have to wind the watch all the way to the end
> 2. you have to wind the watch all the way clicked
> 3. you have to wind the watch all the way until you hear a click
> 4. you have to wind the watch all the way until you feel resistance

Sentence 1 is grammatical but not really idiomatic. Even if the winding does eventually *complete* or *come to a stop*, it sounds strange to speak of a rotational movement having an "end." That would be used more for a linear movement like a slider.

Sentence 2 is not grammatical.

Sentences 3 and 4 are grammatical and nearly idiomatic. I would remove the "all the way" clause and simply say: "You have to wind the watch until you hear a click/feel resistance."

Comment: Do people still use clockwork watches? I would say 'turn the winding knob until the watch is fully wound' and explain how the user will know this (e.g. click, resistance, whatever). I remember being warned by my father not to over-wind my first mechanical watch, as I might break the spring.